# Image in Code Igniter anchor() function

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a model to fetch data from mysql database. I am using the table and pagination library to display data. When displaying the data there is a column called "DELETE", which is used for deleting each rows. Instead of using the text "DELETE" I want to use an image. I have tried a lot to add it in the model but it is not working. Would you please kindly help me?

Thanks in Advance :)

```
function batch_list()
{       
    $config['per_page'] = 15;
    $this->db->select('batchname, class, batchinstructor');
    $this->db->order_by("batchid", "desc"); 
    $rows = $this->db->get('batch',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3))->result_array();

    $sl = $this->uri->segment(3) + 1; // so that it begins from 1 not 0
    foreach ($rows as $count => $row)
        {
            array_unshift($rows[$count], $sl.'.');
             $sl = $sl + 1;

$rows[$count]['batchname'] = anchor('batch_list/get/'.$row['batchname'],$row['batchname']);
$rows[$count]['Edit'] = anchor('update_student/update/'.$row['batchname'],'Edit');
$rows[$count]['Delete'] = anchor('report/'.$row['batchname'],'<img src="base_url().support/images/icons /cross.png" alt="Delete" />"'); //<<< This is where I actually tried/want to add the image


            }
        return $rows;
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please clarify what you mean by *not working*.

Anyway,
for now I am guessing your problem is your escaping, try:

```
anchor('report/'.$row['batchname'], '<img src="'.base_url().'support/images/icons/cross.png" alt="Delete" />');
```

or if you are using the [html helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html) you can use

```
anchor('report/'.$row['batchname'], img('support/images/icons/cross.png'));
```

(if you want the `alt` attribute you will need to use the array form)

```
$img = array(
    'src' => 'support/images/icons/cross.png',
    'alt' => 'Delete'
);

anchor('report/'.$row['batchname'], img($img));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My question wasn't very clear but still you managed to answer right. thanks again. :)